# Laravel custom redirect after Registration with custom flashed session data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

I am building an app with `Laravel 5.8` where, after registration or login, the user is redirected to a custom page along with a flashed session data, displayed on the page, that says "Welcome!".

I noticed that default redirect behavior in the `RegisterController` is a simple string, that does not allow me to add my custom redirect.

```
  * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     *
      protected $redirectTo = '/custompage';
```

I tried modifying this default behavior replacing the string with a function:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    /* generate URL dynamically */
     return redirect('/custompage')->with('status', 'Welcome!');
}
```

But I get the Warning

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) Header may not contain more than a single
>   header, new line detected

So, how to redirect to the custom page AND add my custom flashed data? Of course without modifying any vendor code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this to

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    /* generate URL dynamicaly */
     return '/custompage';
}
```

It only returns path not the and you do not need `redirect()` here.

and added session data using `Session::flash()` or `Session::put()` depending on your requirement.

Comment: Ok but how am I supposed to add the session data then?

Comment: May be using `Session::put()` or `Session::flash()`.

Comment: It works: I added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session; and I flashed the code I needed. Not sure if it is a perfect approach but YOLO

Comment: @Enrico I am glad, I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you described in different ways. A simple way will be to use the url of your custom route in the RegisterController, then add that route to your route and define a controller function accordingly.

You will keep your RegisterController like this:

```
* Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     *
      protected $redirectTo = '/custompage';
```

Then add a route for it:

```
Route::any('custompage', array('as' => 'custompage', 'uses' => 'HomeController@custompage'));
```

And Define a controller function as you desire.

Comment: Problem is I already handled the Route in my web.php file since I have a Route::resource(); when I add another one it throws an error that I redirect too many times

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the `redirectTo` method. This method should return a string not a response object. So it should be like this

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    /* flash data to the session here */
    session(['status', 'Welcome']);
     return '/custompage';
 }
```